# Create valid coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates, spawn

I'm making a snake game and the apples shouldn't spawn inside the snake when randomly spawned on the screen. I have tried looking for a new place for the apples, when they get placed inside the snake with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < snake.size() - 1; i++) {
  if (snake.get(i).xPos == plum.get(0).xPos && snake.get(i).yPos == plum.get(0).yPos) {
    plum.remove(0);
    plum.add(new Coordinate(rollDice(squaresX - 1) * (squareSize + sizeOfSpace) + sizeOfSpace, rollDice(squaresY - 1) * (squareSize + sizeOfSpace) + sizeOfSpace, new Color(199, 7, 255)));
  }
}
```

This is not a good solution so I'm looking for a new one where I can create invalid coordiantes which are the snakes coordinates and valid coordinates that is the rest. So I can randomize the apples new position from just valid coordinates. But I'm not sure how I'm supposed to code this

Comment: Assuming you're calling this in a loop, it seems to me like a perfectly good solution.  Why do you say it's not good?

Comment: If we are in the senario of almost covering up the whole screen with the snake and we just have about 10 or less positions for the apple to spawn. If this is the case then it could go on and on and keep spawning in the snake and always trying to look for a new place. This could be easily avoided if you just randomize the spawn area of the apple using valid coordinates

Answer (score 0):

This is just a general suggestion, but I think it might work for you.
Keep the length of the snake updated all of the time

Now when creating a new apple, create an array of Coordinations of size of the grid size minus snake length. For example: if your grid size is 9x9 and your snake length is 6, create an array of length 75.
Run over the grid and array and add to the array just Coordinations that do not have the snake in them. It should look something like this:

```
int arrayLocation=0;
for(int i=0; i< grid.length();i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length(); j++)
    {
        if (!snakeAtLocation(i,j))
        {
            arr[arrayLocation++] = new Coordinate(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can randomly pick a number n between 0 to `arr.length()`, then retrieve the coordination from `arr[n]` and you should have a coordination without a snake in it. Hope it helps and if you need more detailed example I will provide tommorow as I'm writing this from my phone and I don't have pc right now:)

By the way, this answer if for a simple use case, as it isn't optimized and running with o(n)^2 each time you eat an apple. If you want more optimized solutions, you would have to track the snake location with each move he make. I'll be able to post both answers tommorow if needed:)